# A way to compare dictionary values in python and printing their keys

Tags: python, for-loop

I have written the following code:

```
dict = {"hello" : 3, "dog" : 5, "cat" : 5, "fish" : 1}

biggestKey = max([[dict[key],key] for key in dict])[1]

print(biggestKey)
```

From this I get the result:

> dog

Whereas I actually want to get:

> dog;cat

How can I fix the code?

Comment: don't use built in function name `dict`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all the keys which have the same maximum value, you can do:

```
>>> D = {"hello" : 3, "dog" : 5, "cat" : 5, "fish" : 1}
>>> maxval = max(D.values())
>>> [k for k, v in D.items() if v == maxval]
['cat', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter out the keys that have the max value:

```
>>> d = {"hello" : 3, "dog" : 5, "cat" : 5, "fish" : 1}
>>> print([k for k, v in d.items() if v == max(d.values())})
['dog', 'cat']
```

Or even with a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

d = {"hello" : 3, "dog" : 5, "cat" : 5, "fish" : 1}

dic = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in d.items():
    dic[value].append(key)

print(max(dic.items(), key = itemgetter(0))[1])
# ['dog', 'cat']
```

Comment: How is this syntax you're using called? I'd like to read up on it.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas it's called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: @JustinasMarozas Yep its a list comprehension. Do note that anything written with a list comprehension can be transformed into nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

d = {}

This will do the trick: `max(d, key=d.get)`

Also: `max(d.values())`

Comment: Please avoid to use built in function name `dict` it over write dict object

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
dict_1 = {"hello" : 3, "dog" : 5, "cat" : 5, "fish" : 1}

from collections import defaultdict

d=defaultdict(list)

for j,i in dict_1.items():
    d[i].append(j)

print(d.get(max(d)))
```

output:

```
['cat', 'dog']
```